# Oracle - both get XML date string and convert it to date

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I am decoding an XML file (stored as a CLOB in the database) and there is a field that I want to pull out and store as a date.

If I select the field, I get data:

```
select xmlquery('declare namespace wx = "http://weather.obsfucate.com/rest-3.4/doc/"; //wx:validDateTime/text()' 
       PASSING XMLTYPE(wx.xml_result) 
       RETURNING CONTENT) as VALID_DATETIME
from OPSADM.WEATHER_XML wx
where DATATYPE = 'DailyObservation'
```

returns '2019-08-08T08:00:00+00:00'

If I try to insert that into a table with a DATE data type, it gives me an error: "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got -"

So I try a conversion:

```
 select to_timestamp_tz ('2019-08-08T08:00:00+00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM')  OrigTime
 from dual
```

returns '8/8/2019 8:00:00.000000000 AM +00:0'

But if I try to put those two together, putting the to_timestamp_tz around my xmlquery

```
select to_timestamp_tz (xmlquery('declare namespace wx = "http://weather.obsfucate.com/rest-3.4/doc/"; //wx:validDateTime/text()' 
       PASSING XMLTYPE(wx.xml_result) 
       RETURNING CONTENT), 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') as VALID_DATETIME
from OPSADM.WEATHER_XML wx
where DATATYPE = 'DailyObservation'
```

It returns an error: "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -"

So, it doesn't even know what it expects now.

[This got me part of the way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392840/convert-oracle-string-to-date-wtih-timezone)

[I'm pretty sure I'm missing something important that this shows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228576/why-does-oracles-to-timestamp-tz-return-the-wrong-time-and-or-time-zone), and this code gets me part of the way:

```
 select cast(to_timestamp_tz ('2019-08-08T08:00:00+00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM')
 at time zone 'US/Mountain' as date) as MountainTime
 , to_timestamp_tz ('2019-08-08T08:00:00+00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM')  OrigTime
 from dual
```

I think this shows my time zone:

```
 select sessiontimezone, dbtimezone from dual
```

returns -07:00 and +00:00, and I think the database is in either US Mountain or Central time.

I want to pull out the XML date, convert it to an appropriate date that can be inserted into a table.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to cast it:

```
select 
  to_timestamp_tz (CAST(xmlquery('declare namespace wx = "http://weather.obsfucate.com/rest-3.4/doc/"; //wx:validDateTime/text()' 
  PASSING XMLTYPE(wx.xml_result) 
  RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(100)), 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZH:TZM') as VALID_DATETIME
from OPSADM.WEATHER_XML wx
where DATATYPE = 'DailyObservation'
```

Comment: Oh!  I have it the other way (I added more code I'd tried).  I'll give that a try.

Comment: That works.  Except, it puts in the time as 8:00 am, and I suspect I do need to convert it to US Mountain time.  I'm closer!